# Missing external file

Tags: database

In my site, I'm getting a 404 error (http://www.site.com/&mch57a). I'm guessing it's a problem with a module. Is there a way to trace where this call is coming from, other than disabling modules one at a time? I do have the devel module.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at URL aliases under configuration/Search and metadata or look it up in the url_alias table in the database.

Worst case scenario, try to search "&mch57a" in the entire database, to see which module is generating it.

Comment: I searched the entire database, and it said that there were `18 matches inside table cache_form` I then ran the search again, after checking the other things you mentioned, and it said that there were `20 matches inside table cache_form`.

Comment: can you clear all drupal cache from /admin/config/development/performance and check again, then try to access the page again.

Comment: I cleared all the caches, but it still says there are 25 matches in the same table.

Comment: ok...after some more digging and enabling/disabling modules, clearing caches, etc, I've found that the only entry in the database for that string is in the variable table - in the `css_js_query_string` variable. Why would it be looking for a url?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, but not the workaround - it was caused by the links to Google's webfonts in my info file